# Could not publish the portlet from RAD 7.5 to Websphere Portal Server 6.1

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

I am trying to publish a portlet project which is included in an EAR file from RAD 7.5. If I create new portlet projects, I am able to publish it. But for the projects I have taken from SVN, it is throwing error like this.

> EJPPG0024I: Web application with context root /.FooBar is deployed in
>   the application server but not registered with portal.

I followed the [IBM solution](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21446057) by creating new ear file. But still no luck. Anyone faced this issue and resolved it successfully?

I am also unable to delete the application from the list in Websphere Portal Server after this mess up.

Answer (score 1):

I had been facing the same issue. Tried all the options and then finally found out the issue.
Go to your C:\IBMPortal\WebSphere\wp_profile\config\temp\download\cells\IBMT4\applications and delete all the ears thats you don't want. Keep WSPolicyManager.ear and wps.ear.

Answer (score 0):

There's difference between portlet deployment(in WebSphere Portal) and web application deployment (in WAS). So for admins(not developers) the first one is done within Portal Administration and the second is in WebSphere Admin Console.

Could you check portlet.xml and change portlet id?

Could you upload war file for portlet in Portal Administration?

Comment: 1) I tried changing the portlet id, still could not deploy from RAD.
2) If I upload the war file to the WPS, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the EAR file that is already deployed - do it via the underlying WAS admin console. Then try again from your workspace

Comment: All tried but unsuccessful. Moved on to traditional theme deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the deploy portlet option when you right click the portlet project? That tends to deploy and register the portlet.

Or, have you tried after you have deployed the ear file but it has not registered, run an xml access script in the portal admin console. There should be a sample like RegisterCustomTheme.xml under /doc/xml-samples. Just change the values in it to match thos of your app